Mixing dotted and dashed lines within R ggplot line chart
I'm creating a chart showing educational attainment trends. Here's the data:
structure(
  list(
    region_name = c("Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England", "Bedford", "CIPFA_average", "England"), 
    year = c("2018", "2018", "2018", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2023", "2023", "2023", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2023", "2023", "2023", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2023", "2023", "2023"),
    age = c("Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Early Years", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary"), 
    gap_in_months = c(5.9, 4.51428571428571, 4.6, 6.1, 4.87857142857143, 4.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.1, 5.275, 4.8, 5.3, 5.2375, 4.6, 11.5, 10.2642857142857, 9.2, 14.8, 10.9857142857143, 9.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13.3, 11.425, 10.3, 12.5, 11.775, 10.3, 18.4, 20.7357142857143, 18.1, 21, 20.6642857142857, 18.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.1, 21.04375, 18.8, 21.5, 21.6, 19.2)
  ), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -54L)
)

And the code I'm using:
EPI_chart <- EPI_beds_CIPFA_eng %>%
ggplot(aes(x = year, y = gap_in_months, color = region_name, group = region_name)) +  
geom_line(data = . %>% filter(!is.na(gap_in_months)), size = 1.5, linetype = "solid") +  
geom_line(data = . %>% filter(is.na(gap_in_months)), size = 1.5, linetype = "dotted") +  
facet_wrap(~ age, scales = "free_y") +  theme_minimal()  +
scale_color_manual(values = HT_colours_broad_3)


There are some NA values in the data, for the years 2020 and 2021. I want to fill these in with dashed lines. But my code is not doing this - I'm getting solid lines all the way. Is there any way of filling in the missing data with dotted lines?

How do you want to fill the years 2020 and 2021?

I want the years with data to appear in solid lines (so we'll have solid lines from 2018-19 and 2022-23); then I want dotted lines to join them up (i.e. joining the 2018-19 line to the 2022-23 line).

There might be a more elegant solution, but I broke it up into three time periods (<2020, >2021, and 2019-2022) and created a geom_line for each one of the three periods:
ggplot(EPI_beds_CIPFA_eng, 
       aes(x = year, 
           y = gap_in_months, 
           color = region_name, 
           group = region_name)) +  
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(year < 2020), size = 1.5, linetype = "solid") +  
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(year > 2021), size = 1.5, linetype = "solid") +  
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(year %in% c(2019, 2022)), size = 1.5, linetype = "dotted") +  
  facet_wrap(~ age, scales = "free_y") +  
  theme_minimal()  



There are a couple of things I would change here.
Firstly, ensure that your years are numeric so that the x axis does not skip missing years and you do not have to specify a grouping variable in addition to colour.
Secondly, explicitly create the values for the projected missing lines in your data before plotting. Doing so with data manipulation (e.g. with approx) rather than manual filtering means that it will be easier to re-use your code if your data changes:
EPI_beds_CIPFA_eng %>% 
  group_by(region_name, age) %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year), 
         missing = is.na(gap_in_months),
         gap = approx(year[!missing], gap_in_months[!missing], xo = year)$y,
         unfilled_gap = ifelse(missing, NA, gap_in_months)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, gap, color = region_name)) +  
  geom_line(aes(y = unfilled_gap), linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_line(linetype = 3, linewidth = 1.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ age, scales = "free_y") +  
  theme_minimal()


